# Is there an XPath-like syntax in XAML that can get items out of a collection?

Tags: wpf, xml, xaml, binding

I have a Dictionary object in my ViewModel with key/values that translate words on the View.

It is possible to get the language information as an **XML object** and then pick out the translated phrase with XPath, something like this:

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{TranslatorDictionaryXml}" Text="{Binding XPath=/terms/term[key='edit']/value[@lang='en-US']}"/>
```

But is there a similar way to do this with a **non-XML object** which offers some kind of XPath-like syntax, e.g.

PSEUDO-CODE:

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{CurrentLanguageTranslatorDictionary}" Text="{Binding path=Key['edit']}"/>
```

I don't want to bind a collection to a ListView or any other collection element, but want to bind the one Translator object to **individual TextBlocks and TextBoxes and ToolTips**, etc. and then use some kind of path syntax to get a particular item out of the bound collection.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do both, there's an XPath property on a [Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding_members.aspx) as well.  There's some good examples of how to do it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749287.aspx), and throughout the [binding how-to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752039.aspx) samples.  You can [also use a collection's indexer](http://sachabarber.net/?p=219) to do it, but it doesn't need single quotes or escaped quotes.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Countries[US]}" />

public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Countries = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Countries.Add("US", "United States");
        Countries.Add("CA", "Canada");

        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> Countries { get; set; }
}
```